# Как выводить последнее видео с YouTube-канала?

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, youtube, youtube-api

Как вывести последнее опубликованное видео с произвольного YouTube-канала на наш сайт?

Comment: изучите youtube api

Comment: Там нужно использовать App Key, по этому хотелось бы другой способ...

Comment: Думаю только через серверную часть, так как в том же JS не возможны кросс-доменные запросы а так можно спарсить по средствам регулярного выражения в том же PHP

Answer (score 2):

Запрос `get last video youtube channel js` в гугле даёт нужный результат. <del>Ссылка на gist: https://gist.github.com/AAlakkad/7749594</del>

Без бэкенда или API ключа это никак не сделать. Для начала, необходимо сконвертировать имя канала в его ID [вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29757022/5463706).

Вот пример кода на PHP:

```
<?php

$id = NULL;
$channel_id = 'someChannelID';

$xml = simplexml_load_file(sprintf('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=%s', $channel_id));

if (!empty($xml->entry[0]->children('yt', true)->videoId[0])){
    $id = $xml->entry[0]->children('yt', true)->videoId[0];
}

echo $id; // Outputs the video ID.
```

По мотивам [EN SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29757022/5463706)

Comment: Не работает, youtube запрос выдает No longer available

Comment: А другие варианты с гугла пробовали? Там их не один.